# How to make a calculator for many numbers in string?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, calculator, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk

I need to create a calculator in python. In the beginning I have a string with numbers and a word like: `str = '5 plus 5'` I can do this for 2 numbers, but when string looks like: `hard_str = '5 plus 10 divide 2'` I need to know how to do calculations in this case. Basically, how does google voice assistant make calculations when I say `str = '2 minus 20 divide 4'`?

def math(text):

'''text is a string like "22 plus 5" '''

```
ADD = ['+', 'plus',]
SUBTRACT = ['-', 'minus',]
MULTIPLY = ['*', 'multiply', 'x']
DIVIDE = ['/', 'divide',]


expression = text


expression = expression.lower().split()

expression_left = expression[0]
expression_middle = expression[1]
expression_right = expression[2]

answer = None

if expression_middle in ADD:
    answer = int(expression_left) + int(expression_right)
if expression_middle in SUBTRACT:
    answer = int(expression_left) - int(expression_right)
if expression_middle in MULTIPLY:
    answer = int(expression_left) * int(expression_right)
if expression_middle in DIVIDE:
    answer = int(expression_left) / float(expression_right)

result = str(answer)
return f'Result of, {text} is {result}'
```

Works for 2 numbers, what to do if there 2+2*50\8*3

Comment: If you evaluate left to right, you could remove each part of the string recursively as you process them.

Comment: Change all `plus`, `minus`, `multiply` and `divide` in the string to `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`, then use `eval(str)` to get the result.

Comment: @4ndy has a good approach, but doing it that way violates order of operations.

Comment: Did you tag this "voice-recognition" or "google-assistant-sdk" because you're doing this using voice or for the Google Assistant? Or were those just examples?

Comment: Well i'm using google Cloud Speech API, and google-assistant is an example how they doing this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i couldn't resolve this without eval()...for now...here is how i did that:

`divide = '/'`
   `multiply = '*'`
   `minus = '-'`
   `plus = '+'`

`def hard_math(*text):
        result = eval(text[0].replace('плюс', plus).replace('минус', minus).replace('x', multiply).replace('x', multiply).replace('/',divide))
        return str(result)`